# OptaPlanner upgrade to TimeFold results in behavior difference with nullables

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

I have a planning variable annotated with `@PlanningVariable(nullable = true)`. I'm using the exhaustive search (brute force) because this is for unit tests and I need to ensure the result comes out the same each time.

I have trace logging turned on to see how the search occurs.

In OptaPlanner 9.44.0, the start of the search looks like this:

```
Move treeId (1-0), score (null), expandable (true), move ({null -> null}).
Move treeId (1-1), score (null), expandable (true), move ({null -> <something not null>}}).
Move treeId (1-2), score (null), expandable (true), move ({null -> <something not null>}).
Move treeId (1-3), score (null), expandable (true), move ({null -> <something not null>}}).
```

In TimeFold 1.2.0, the start of the search looks like this:

```
Move (... {null -> null}) filtered out by a selection filter (Doable moves only).
Move treeId (1-0), score (null), expandable (true), move (... {null -> <something not null>}).
Move treeId (1-1), score (null), expandable (true), move (... {null -> <something not null>}).
Move treeId (1-2), score (null), expandable (true), move (... {null -> <something not null>}).
```

The difference is that the null assignment is filtered out in TimeFold.

I need that null to be part of the search. I haven't defined any selection filters -- this is just the default behavior. How can I get the null to be included in the search? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what the output means? (But definitely a bunch of tests that are passing in OptaPlanner are failing in TimeFold.)

Answer (score 1):

There was [a change](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/commit/0bc4ec172dfe1dc5643543ba2e9d9afecbbadbda) in Timefold Solver recently which likely did this. If your planning variable is `nullable`, then this looks like [a bug](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/309).

The fix is available since Timefold Solver 1.3.0.

Comment: Thank you, it's great to know I'm not going crazy :) For my own planning purposes, can you give some indication as to when 1.3.0 might come out? E.g., is it days, weeks, or months away?

Comment: We strive for monthly releases, so unless anything goes massively wrong, a release should show up this month.